# How to use .svg file in Jetpack Compose for Desktop?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I am trying to use a `.svg` (vector file) to show an image but I am stuck and not able to do it. Is there any way I can use it, I tried to use it like this

```
Image(imageFromResource("svg_file_name.svg"),contentDescription="")
```

But it throws an error :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to Image::makeFromEncoded
    at org.jetbrains.skija.Image.makeFromEncoded(Image.java:130)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.DesktopImageAsset_desktopKt.imageFromResource(DesktopImageAsset.desktop.kt:77)
    at ComposableSingletons$MainKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(main.kt:103)
    at ComposableSingletons$MainKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(main.kt:98)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt$Surface$6.invoke(Surface.kt:267)
    at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt$Surface$6.invoke(Surface.kt:254)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt.Surface-F-jzlyU(Surface.kt:251)
    at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt.Surface-F-jzlyU(Surface.kt:110)
    at androidx.compose.material.CardKt.Card-F-jzlyU(Card.kt:66)
    at MainKt.ShowCanvasIsEmpty(main.kt:93)
    at MainKt.DisplayMainUI(main.kt:78)
    at MainKt$main$1$1.invoke(main.kt:60)
    at MainKt$main$1$1.invoke(main.kt:55)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.material.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:252)
    at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
    at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:80)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:72)
    at MainKt$main$1.invoke(main.kt:55)
    at MainKt$main$1.invoke(main.kt:53)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.AppWindow_desktopKt$Window$1$1.invoke(AppWindow.desktop.kt:97)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.AppWindow_desktopKt$Window$1$1.invoke(AppWindow.desktop.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.AppWindow$show$1.invoke(AppWindow.desktop.kt:446)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.AppWindow$show$1.invoke(AppWindow.desktop.kt:444)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.AppWindow$onCreate$1.invoke(AppWindow.desktop.kt:420)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.AppWindow$onCreate$1.invoke(AppWindow.desktop.kt:419)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.ComposeWindow$setContent$1$1.invoke(ComposeWindow.desktop.kt:95)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.ComposeWindow$setContent$1$1.invoke(ComposeWindow.desktop.kt:94)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.ComposeWindow$setContent$1.invoke(ComposeWindow.desktop.kt:91)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.ComposeWindow$setContent$1.invoke(ComposeWindow.desktop.kt:90)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:148)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.Wrapper_desktopKt$ProvideDesktopCompositionsLocals$1.invoke(Wrapper.desktop.kt:51)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.Wrapper_desktopKt$ProvideDesktopCompositionsLocals$1.invoke(Wrapper.desktop.kt:50)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.Wrapper_desktopKt.ProvideDesktopCompositionsLocals(Wrapper.desktop.kt:48)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.Wrapper_desktopKt.access$ProvideDesktopCompositionsLocals(Wrapper.desktop.kt:1)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.Wrapper_desktopKt$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.desktop.kt:40)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.Wrapper_desktopKt$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.desktop.kt:39)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3324)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2575)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2571)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotState.kt:523)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2564)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime(Composer.kt:2515)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:476)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime(Recomposer.kt:727)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:432)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.Wrapper_desktopKt.setContent(Wrapper.desktop.kt:39)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.ComposeLayer.initOwner(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:268)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.ComposeLayer.access$initOwner(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:49)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.ComposeLayer$Wrapped.init(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:87)
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.SkiaLayer.checkInit(SkiaLayer.kt:69)
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.SkiaLayer.access$checkInit(SkiaLayer.kt:23)
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.SkiaLayer$2.hierarchyChanged(SkiaLayer.kt:57)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processHierarchyEvent(Component.java:6819)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6438)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5027)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4859)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.addNotify(Component.java:7123)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Canvas.addNotify(Canvas.java:104)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4791)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4791)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4791)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4791)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4791)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(JRootPane.java:733)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2800)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:787)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Frame.java:490)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:1049)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1732)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1679)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1032)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.ComposeWindow.setVisible(ComposeWindow.desktop.kt:110)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.AppWindow.show(AppWindow.desktop.kt:449)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.AppWindow.show$default(AppWindow.desktop.kt:435)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.AppWindow_desktopKt$Window$1.run(AppWindow.desktop.kt:96)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Desktop Compose has `painterResource`, which supports:

- SVG
- [XML vector drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources)
- raster formats (BMP, GIF, HEIF, ICO, JPEG, PNG, WBMP, WebP)

To load an image from other places (file storage, database, network), use these functions inside `LaunchedEffect` or `remember`: `loadSvgPainter`,  `loadXmlImageVector`, `loadImageBitmap`

Comment: Where does it come from? I can't import it from `import androidx.compose.ui.res.`, am I missing a dependency? I would have guessed androidx.compose.ui:ui from gradle dependencies...

Comment: @JonasVautherin the API was changed, now you can use `painterResource`. I've updated my answer

Comment: If you try to load a file outside the resources you still have to use ``loadSvgPainter``

Comment: Could you use this function in the common folder? How could we import it there?

Comment: @rylexr I don't have an example project with a common module, I suggest you try it yourself. But I don't think it will work, because Android `painterResource` expects the `Int` parameter, which is the resource ID generated by the Android resources plugin. The organization of Android resources is quite different from the JVM.

Comment: Side-question: Are there limitations on what SVG is supported? I have a collection of SVGs for playing cards here where the back face renders and the front faces mostly don't... the images are the same size, and IDEA and Chrome render both fine. In particular, it seems like the `<use/>` element might not work at all... which is unfortunately extremely common in this sort of SVG...

Comment: @Hakanai you can report issue with svg sample to [official repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc), so it will be fixed in future releases, or you'll get a workaround

Comment: https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues/4102

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for `Icon` you can use `ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.res_id)`

```
 Icon(imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_reddit_grey),
                    contentDescription = "Reddit smol icon" )
```